# Django Rest Swagger -> No Authentication + multiple apps

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

We are looking to use `django swagger` for generating REST API docs. Our app consists of many sub apps and all views use `JWT` authentication. Document seems very lacking and just mentions the adding of url. This shows me error `400 : ["The schema generator did not return a schema Document"] http://10.0.0.61:8001/API/?format=openapi`

```
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view

schema_view = get_swagger_view(title="HashCove REST API")
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'info/', BackendVersion.as_view()),
    url(r'^transaction/', include('kyc_rest_services.kyc_connect_transaction_manager.urls')),
    url(r'^drive/', include('kyc_rest_services.carbon_drive.urls')),
    url(r'^channels/', include('kyc_rest_services.channels.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('kyc_rest_services.kyc_connect_accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^API/', schema_view, name="docs")
]
```

Can it show all the APIs in the other apps and no authentication required.